# Generating data and saving estimates in a loop in R

Tags: r

I'm a beginner with R and programming in general and i'm having some problems with this loop. 
Basically i want to generate 10,000 estimates of beta_2 when n=10 and store them in a vector where the estimator in question is given by the formula (cov(x,y)/var(x)). 
Ive tried the following code but it only yields the first estimate correctly and fills the other positions in the vector as NA. Any tips to solve this?

```
X <- rlnorm(n, X_meanlog, X_sdlog)
u <- rnorm(n, u_mean, u_sd)
Y <- beta_1 + beta_2 * X + u
rep <- 10000
vect <- vector(mode="numeric", length=rep)
for(i in 1:rep){vect[i] <-(cov(X,Y) / var(X))[i]}
```

Comment: See the result of `cov(X, Y) / var(X)`. It's a scalar and when you index `(cov(X, Y) / var(X))[2]` you are accessing a nonexisting vector element, an `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

You must simulate the vectors `X` and `Y` inside the loop.

```
n <- 10
X_meanlog <- 0
X_sdlog <- 1
u_mean <- 0
u_sd <- 1

beta_1 <- 2
beta_2 <- 3

set.seed(5276)    # Make the results reproducible

rept <- 10000
vect <- vector(mode="numeric", length=rept)
for(i in 1:rept){
  X <- rlnorm(n, X_meanlog, X_sdlog)
  u <- rnorm(n, u_mean, u_sd)
  Y <- beta_1 + beta_2 * X + u
  vect[i] <- (cov(X, Y) / var(X))
}

mean(vect)
#[1] 3.002527
```

You can also run the following simpler simulation.

```
set.seed(5276)    # Make the results reproducible

X <- replicate(rept, rlnorm(n, X_meanlog, X_sdlog))
u <- replicate(rept, rnorm(n, u_mean, u_sd))
Y <- beta_1 + beta_2 * X + u

vect2 <- sapply(seq_len(rept), function(i)
  cov(X[, i], Y[, i]) / var(X[, i])
  )

mean(vect2)
#[1] 3.001131
```